# Variable selections for Mixed data(categorical and numerical)

Tags: feature-selection

I have a dataset I want to do a logistic regression on. The data contains some numerical data and categorical data. The categorical data have many different values. My approach is to do a one-hot encoding and bin the values accordingly(I am thinking of using clustering to bin but don't know how.) but how should I proceed? I am new to training models. Do I apply standardization after the step? The package I am thinking about is sklearn.randomforest. Any help would be much appreciated!